# How to get the author name of the document which is uploaded in Box using Box API?

Tags: java, box-api

My task is to get the **Document informations** which are uploaded in **Box** for the particular user using Java. I am using **Box API for java** for achieve this task. I can able to connect with the user's Box profile and get the documents. But I am not able to get the author name of the document. That is the name of the user who upload the file.

Anybody know how to get that information?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what SDK you're using, but the 'author' of the document is listed in the created_by attribute of the `[files object](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-file-object-2) e.g.

```
{
    "type": "file",
    "id": "5000948880",
    "sequence_id": "3",
    "etag": "3",
    "sha1": "134b65991ed521fcfe4724b7d814ab8ded5185dc",
    "name": "tigers.jpeg",
    "description": "a picture of tigers",
    "size": 629644,
    "path_collection": {
        "total_count": 2,
        "entries": [
            {
                "type": "folder",
                "id": "0",
                "sequence_id": null,
                "etag": null,
                "name": "All Files"
            },
            {
                "type": "folder",
                "id": "11446498",
                "sequence_id": "1",
                "etag": "1",
                "name": "Pictures"
            }
        ]
    },
    "created_at": "2012-12-12T10:55:30-08:00",
    "modified_at": "2012-12-12T11:04:26-08:00",
    "created_by": {
        "type": "user",
        "id": "17738362",
        "name": "sean rose",
        "login": "sean@box.com"
    },
    "modified_by": {
        "type": "user",
        "id": "17738362",
        "name": "sean rose",
        "login": "sean@box.com"
    },
    "owned_by": {
        "type": "user",
        "id": "17738362",
        "name": "sean rose",
        "login": "sean@box.com"
    },
    "shared_link": {
        "url": "https://www.box.com/s/rh935iit6ewrmw0unyul",
        "download_url": "https://www.box.com/shared/static/rh935iit6ewrmw0unyul.jpeg",
        "vanity_url": null,
        "is_password_enabled": false,
        "unshared_at": null,
        "download_count": 0,
        "preview_count": 0,
        "access": "open",
        "permissions": {
            "can_download": true,
            "can_preview": true
        }
    },
    "parent": {
        "type": "folder",
        "id": "11446498",
        "sequence_id": "1",
        "etag": "1",
        "name": "Pictures"
    },
    "item_status": "active"
}
```